# Is offering money for a penetration test allowed

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Today [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93093/pentest-challenge-how-secure-is-the-following-site) popped up in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3657423#3657423) because it contained an e-mail address.

9-out-of-10 of those questions turn out to be spam or otherwise low-quality.

As that question offers money I wondered if that was allowed/on-topic but nor your [help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) nor a search on meta rendered results that seems to answer that question.

Are questions asking for this community to do work and get paid for that allowed and/or on-topic.

If not, how do you prefer those get flagged?

Comment: Sounds like that would have been more suitable for an ad or http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @rene, Actually the "who" is important. Are such "bounty" questions on-topic if they are posted by StackExchange?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Flag it as spam. I think that's such an edge case it's not worth trying to document and I got plenty of flags on the question.

Offering money for a pentest is solicitation of commerce at a point-in-time, so it's not helpful in our Q&A site format for the same reasons that link-only answers are discouraged.